# Find distances between points through a raster

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, spatial-analyst, cost-path, shortest-path

I have a set of 79 points located overlaid on a raster that defines distance through coastal waters:  each cell equals 100 metres, with NoData for coast and islands.

I can use this raster to create a new raster with the distance of each cell to the nearest point using both the Cost Distance or Path Distance tools.

I would like, however, to identify for each point the identity of the nearest other point and the distance to it through the raster.

I am using ArcMap 10.0 with access to the Spatial Analyst tools.

Answer (score 3):

I am afraid that you will need to create 79 distance rasters with the distance for each point. This can be done in model builder (with iterate features) or with python (loop on the ID with make feature layers).

Once you have your 79 rasters, you can use "extract multi values to points" that will yield a origin-destination cost matrix in your attribute table.

Finally, compute the minimum value and the field that contains the minimum value for all points

```
yourmin = min(!field1!, ..., !field79!)

yourClosestPoint = [!field1!, ..., !field79!].index(!yourmin!)
```

Comment: Thank you for the prompt reply radouxju, I was rather afraid that would be the answer.